# How to login to a restored Odoo database

Tags: odoo, odoo-16, odoo-ce

I created an Odoo database on Odoo saas (v16) with a website. I then decided to move the database to Odoo CE. So I backed up the database and restored it to the CE server. I can see that the database has been created correctly because the website works. However, I am unable to log in to the database at /web. I have tried using the email and password of the users that were defined in the saas database but it doesn't work. I am unable to reset the password because I haven't yet set up SMTP. I have the master password that I set when I set up the original database. I can see in psql that the two users that existed in the saas database exist in res_users but the passwords are not accepted. How can I log in?

Comment: I am assuming you have installed CE on server or local instance 
which means you have complete control of your database, and you can change the password directly from the database 
if you can open psql without trouble, you may run this command that will change all users password to 'admin'
`update res_users set password ='admin'; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have installed CE on the server or local instance, which means you have complete control of your database, and you can change the password directly from the database if you can open psql without trouble. You may run this command that will change all user's passwords to 'admin'

`update res_users set password ='admin';`